# How to prevent updating of a specific package?

Tags: updates, applications, command-line

I would like to update just the base of elementary system and not the all installed apps.

I can run `sudo apt-get install package-name` to upgrade the package if it is already installed. Whereas I can also run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade all the packages.

I want to upgrade just the elementary OS and no other app installed later on. Such as Noise(Music) *should be* upgraded VLC *should not*. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm curious: Why?

Comment: @quassy I have a few apps that are quite huge to update frequently thus I need to update the system time to time and update these apps once in a month or two.

Comment: Interesting, o_O

Comment: I have edited the post, for better search results. Feel free to revert (roll back) if it diverts your actual post intention :) @Adityaultra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CLI: (**Recommended**, see [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13444886/) and note)

**Keeping on hold**: (suggest: use *dpkg*)

- **Apt**

  ```
  sudo apt-mark hold package-name
  ```
- **Dpkg**

  ```
  sudo -s 
  echo package-name hold | dpkg --set-selections
  apt-get update
  ```

  *Note*: Replace *package-name* with yours, for example, `google-chrome-stable`

*Removing a Hold*:

- **Apt**

  ```
  sudo apt-mark unhold package-name
  ```
- **Dpkg**

  ```
  sudo -s 
  echo package-name install | dpkg --set-selections
  apt-get update
  ```

  **Note**: This CLI method can hold/lock packages while updating through `apt-get upgrade` and also using `software-updater`.

---

Here my test with `google-chrome-stable`. You can clearly identify even chrome update is available but that is *kept back*.

```
ravan@ravan:~$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable:
Installed: 44.0.2403.107-1
Candidate: 46.0.2490.86-1
Version table:
    46.0.2490.86-1 0
       500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
*** 44.0.2403.107-1 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ravan@ravan:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

<sub>reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction%20to%20Holding%20Packages)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Use `synaptic`:

*Note*: This method  holds/locks packages when using `software-updater` but not with `apt-get upgrade`

To install synaptic, open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

<sub>I will consider `google-chrome-stable` as example:</sub>

- Open `synaptic` and search for `chrome` and select it.
- Hit *Package* in top menu and choose *Force version*

  In the dropdown, select the version you like. ( I am not sure this step is necessary for your requirement )
- Hit *Package* in top menu and choose "Lock version".

  (then it will change to red color)

  Now your installed version is locked. Therefore Updater will **no longer notify you any updates until you unlock it**.

Similarly apply lock for installed packages.

---

Here I have tested with `google-chrome-stable`

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

**Before lock**:

[image: Imgur]

**After lock**:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2):

Finally, a *simple* solution.

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

The above command open the file, if not there, it will create.

Here you want to hold `vlc` (for example) to specific version.

Now add the following lines to the above file:

```
Package: vlc
Pin: version 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Here,

- `Package` is package name.
- `Pin` is version you want to hold

After that run : `sudo apt-get update`

---

**Test**:

Before pin:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ apt-cache policy vlc
vlc:
   Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
   Candidate: 2.2.1~trusty1
```

After pin:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ apt-cache policy vlc
vlc:
    Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
    Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
    Package pin: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
```

To revert,  remove the content of `/etc/apt/preferences` file.