# No wingpanel after installing indicator-synapse

Tags: wingpanel

I have installed indicator-synapse using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

After reboot, wing panel disappeared. It seems because of `indicator-synapse` wingpanel disappeared.

- How to get back wingpanel
- How to install `indicator-synapse` without affecting wingpanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the installed indicator synapse:

Open terminal using shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>, if you not modified)

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-synapse
```

Now logout/login. Your wing panel will be back

---

**To install without effecting wingpanel** :

I have found similar bug report (status:invalid) [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1358490).

From the post:

> The crash seems related to the fact that indicator-synapse was built using libgee 1.0 instead of libgee 0.8.

**The solution**:

Manually install [indicator-synapse](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/unstable-upstream/+sourcepub/4275868/+listing-archive-extra).

- Download package,  for [64-bit](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/unstable-upstream/+files/indicator-synapse_0~529-0~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb) and for [32-bit](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/unstable-upstream/+files/indicator-synapse_0~529-0~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb).
- Install from Software Center.

*Note*: Once you update synapse via package manager the problem of course will reappear.(Quoted from the same link)

To eliminate that, hold the `indicator-synapse`

See [how to lock/hold an app](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3121/2708)