# How do I avoid Kernel 3.19 updates?

Tags: kernel

I bought a new (high end) laptop recently and elementary OS runs like a dream on it.  The bad news is that I had to update the kernel to 4.3* to get everything working properly and I subsequently removed 3.19.

Now software updates is trying to push the original kernel and I want to know how this can be avoided.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd say you are using a old kernel and not 4.3. Open a console and type uname -r . then write here the output.

Comment: +Maccer  I would be happy if that was true but ....4.3.0-040300-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open synaptic and search for `linux-image`

Now select the one which you don't want to update.

Now click on `package` in menu bar --> click on `lock version`

[image: Imgur]

You have to repeat the same for all the entries in `software-updater` related to `3.19`

You can also use alternative methods mentioned at:

[How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

**Note**:

This will stop updating the desired kernel, at the same time, when you run `software-updater`, you will get *partial updates*.